# QGIS Plugin -> QgsVertexMarker points missing: Anyway to find out which points are not visible?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, gps, markers

I am trying to plot live feed of three GPSs running at 10 Hz using my own QGIS plugin. I was using QgsRubberband initially which worked fine. I recently added QgsVertexMarker to plot every data points on the canvas.

```
# Adding vertex Markers
self.vertexMarker=QgsVertexMarker (self.canvas)
self.vertexMarker.setColor(self.lineColor)
self.vertexMarker.setIconSize(2)
self.vertexMarker.setIconType(QgsVertexMarker.ICON_BOX)
self.vertexMarker.setPenWidth(3)
self.vertexMarker.show()
self.vertexMarker.setCenter(p)
self.vertexMarkers.append(self.vertexMarker)
```

The code runs fine but at 10Hz data seems to cause some missing point specially when zoomed in and out quickly. [![GPS Feed plot][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIJlV.png

In the image, you can see 03 GPS markers and its trail created using rubberbands and vertexmarkers. If you look closely, you can see missing vertexMarker points in the Red and Green streams. I can assure you that data is not missing and it did receive the points.

I used

```
self.vertexMarkers_tpv[-1].isVisible()
self.vertexMarkers_tpv[-1].isVisibleTo(None)
```

to verify the vertexMarker are set to be visible and visible to Scene(I think). Each time it returns True but somehow still the points are missing

> bool QGraphicsItem::isVisibleTo(const QGraphicsItem * parent) const

```
`Returns true if the item is visible to parent; otherwise, false is returned. Parent can be 0, in which case this function will return whether the item is visible to the scene or not.An item may not be visible to its ancestors even if isVisible() is true. It may also be visible to its ancestors even if isVisible() is false. If any ancestor is hidden, the item itself will be implicitly hidden, in which case this function will return false.
```

In short, I know at lower data rate say 5Hz things works fine but as soon as data rate is 10Hz I start to lose points. If there is a way that I can tell if certain point is not plotted (feedback mechanism), I can re-plot the points?

EDIT: the same behaviour can be seen with the rubberband. it's just hard to identify with 10Hz data.

Comment: Could you show the entire code?